# MySQL - SELECT AVG on some rows and SUM on all

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, average

I am trying to average values of some specific rows but sum volumes of all of them.

I have 2 tables, one called `exchanges` and another one called `valid_country`.

**exchanges**

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     id    |   ref    |     country  |   value  | volume |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     1     |  1029    |      DE      |   1 000  |   100  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     2     |  1029    |      US      |   2 000  |   250  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     3     |  1029    |      FR      |   3 500  |   300  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     4     |  1053    |      UK      |   1 200  |   110  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     5     |  1029    |      RU      |     900  |    70  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

This table contains many references (ref) which have different countries, themselves with different values and volumes.

**valid_country**

```
+--------------+--------------+
|     ref      |   country    |
+--------------+--------------+
|    1029      |     US       |
+--------------+--------------+
|    1029      |     RU       |
+--------------+--------------+
|    1053      |     UK       |
+--------------+--------------+
```

This table lists all the 'good' countries for which values can be averaged.

#### What I would like as a result query is :

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
|   ref    | AVG(value) | SUM(volume) |
+----------+------------+-------------+
|  1029    |    1 450   |     720     |
+----------+------------+-------------+
|  1053    |    1 200   |     110     |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Firstly ref are `GROUP BY`.
Ref 1029 shall `AVERAGE` values of only US and RU (because of table valid_country) but `SUM` volumes of all countries.
Same thing for Ref 1053 but since there's only one row it is easy.

Here is a little [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16969/4). The SQL request is false since it averages all countries and not only the good one.

Comment: Well first of all, you need to JOIN your two tables, so that in your query you know which countries are considered “good”.

Comment: (And btw., your fiddle inserts the values for the second table into the first one. Since the first one contains those columns as well, it doesn’t throw an error, but it doesn’t give an actual testable result.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you ! I've edited my fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16969/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comparison to `valid_country` needs to use both `ref` and `country`:

```
SELECT e.ref,
       AVG(CASE WHEN vc.country IS NOT NULL THEN e.value END) AS average,
       SUM(e.volume) AS volume
FROM exchanges e LEFT JOIN
     valid_country vc
     ON vc.country = e.country AND vc.ref = e.ref
GROUP BY e.ref;
```

This doesn't matter for your sample data but it might be important for the larger problem.

Comment: Well senn Gordon. It was indeed the full comparison I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and the [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement to ignore some values in the `AVG` ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16969/14)):

```
SELECT e.ref,
       AVG(CASE WHEN vc.country IS NOT NULL THEN e.value END) AS average,
       SUM(e.volume) AS volume
FROM exchanges e
LEFT JOIN valid_country vc ON ( vc.country = e.country )
GROUP BY e.ref
```

`CASE`returns `NULL`if not matched, and `AVG` ignores those values:

```
|  ref | average | volume |
|------|---------|--------|
| 1029 |    1450 |    720 |
| 1053 |    1200 |    110 |
```

Comment: Thank you. That works fine! Comparing your query and Nico Weisenauer's one on my large db to check which one is the faster. I'll give answer after tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using case statement in the aggregate function in mysql.[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16969/25)

```
SELECT e.ref,e.country , AVG(case when c.country = e.country then e.value end) as avge,SUM(volume)
FROM exchanges e left join valid_country as c on e.country = c.country
GROUP BY e.ref
```

Answer (score 1):

This query makes use of a subquery to deliver the correct results:

```
SELECT e1.ref,subq.avg,SUM(volume)
FROM exchanges e1,
 (SELECT e2.ref, AVG(value) as avg 
  FROM exchanges e2, valid_country vc
  WHERE e2.country = vc.country
  GROUP BY e2.ref) as subq
WHERE e1.ref = subq.ref
GROUP BY ref
```

Comment: Thank you. That works fine! Comparing your query  and Peter Lang's one on my large db to check which one is the faster. I'll give answer after tests.